# Override search requirement in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We search on the following fields in our index:

- individual_name *(string)*
- organisation_name *(string)*
- profile *(string)*
- locations *(string)*
- nationwide *(boolean)*

If a user searches for "optometrist" in "Hamilton", and an optometrist in our index has listed themselves as "nationwide" (but not specifically in Hamilton), desired behaviour is that the optometrist would show up with the Hamilton results - effectively ignoring the location requirement.

We're currently running a `multi_match` query, an example of which is below.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "optometrist",
                    "zero_terms_query": "all",
                    "operator": "and",
                    "fields": [
                        "individual_name^1.2",
                        "organisation_name^1.5",
                        "profile",
                        "accreditations"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": [{
                    "term": {
                        "locations" : "hamilton"
                    }
                }],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be modified so documents with `"nationwide": "yes"` are returned for this query, regardless of location?

I've tried an `or` query under the `and`, but of course that ignored the `multi_match`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will give you the desired results:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "optometrist",
                    "zero_terms_query": "all",
                    "operator": "and",
                    "fields": [
                        "individual_name^1.2",
                        "organisation_name^1.5",
                        "profile",
                        "accreditations"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "or": [
                        {"term": {"locations" : "hamilton"}},
                        {'term' : {'nationwide' : 'yes'}}        
                 ],
            }
        }
    }
}
```